# How can I clean the output from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

[Picture of the sample.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LGSh.png)

I am having a terrible time getting my code working. I want my code to clean the output from a csv file so that it looks like this.

```
Date High Avg Low

1    7    0   -8

2    5    0   -6
```

I've tried a lot of different things but can't get rid of the semicolons... Instead of getting a cleaner output, I get this:

```
Date;High;Avg;Low;;;;;;;;;;;;;']

['1;5;0;-6;;;;;;;;;;;;;']

['2;7;0;-8;;;;;;;;;;;;;']
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv


def tempData():
    with open("tempdata.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',', quotechar=':')
        tempList = list(reader)

    return tempList


def main():
    tempList = tempData()
    for line in tempList:
        print(line)


main()
```

Comment: try with pandas? `pandas.read_csv(<path_name>, delimiter=';')`

Comment: would be helpful if you could add the CSV too, not whole maybe 3-4 lines along with headers.

Comment: it seems that you have to use a semicolon `;` as a delimiter, not a coma `,`.

Comment: delimiter should be set to ';' quotechar will default to double quote. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

An example of the CSV will be useful for debugging your code

Comment: add a sample from the csv please (few lines)

Comment: Added a picture of the sample. See the edited post.

Comment: @Steffe Can you add the content of the CSV file by opening it in a text editor like notepad or notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('tempdata.csv', delimiter=';')
```

Obviously you'll need to have pandas installed - `pip install pandas`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use pandas in this assignment. Is there a way to do this without pandas?

Answer (score 0):

This one is simple than what you tried if the assignment didn't tell you to use some functions.

```
f=open("tempdata.csv").readlines()
for i in f:
i=i.rstrip().split(";")
    print "\t".join(i)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I just need to put this into two functions (one that reads the csv file and one that makes the output readable). Should be easy!

Comment: Good luck. @Steffe